# Calculating average based on distinct ID while preserving all the data in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

If I have data like so:

```
+------+----+-------+-------+
| year | id | value | group |
+------+----+-------+-------+
| 2019 |  1 |    10 | A     |
| 2019 |  1 |    10 | B     |
| 2019 |  2 |    20 | A     |
| 2019 |  3 |    30 | A     |
| 2019 |  2 |    20 | B     |
| 2020 |  1 |     5 | A     |
| 2020 |  1 |     5 | B     |
| 2020 |  2 |    10 | A     |
| 2020 |  3 |    15 | A     |
| 2020 |  2 |    10 | B     |
+------+----+-------+-------+
```

Is there a way to calculate the average `value` based on the distinct `id` while preserving all the data?

I need to do this because I will also have `WHERE` clause(s) to filter other columns in the table, but I also need to get an overall view of the data in the case the `WHERE` clause(s) are not added (these WHERE filters will be added by an automated software in the OUTERMOST query which I can't control).

The `group` column is an example.

For the above example, the results should be:

`Overall --> 20 for 2019 and 10 for 2020`

`WHERE group = 'A'` --> 20 for 2019 and 10 for 2020

`WHERE group = 'B'` --> 15 for 2019 and 7.5 for 2020

I tried to do the following:

```sql
SELECT 
  year,
  AVG(IF(id = LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id), NULL, value)) AS avg
FROM table
WHERE group = 'A' -- this clause may or may not exist
GROUP BY year
```

Basically I was thinking that if I order by id and check the previous row to see if it has the same id, the value should be `NULL` and thus it would not be counted into the calculation, but unfortunately I can't put analytical functions inside `aggregate` functions.

Comment: Window function is applied after HAVING, so your code is not legal. Provide desired output for shown sample data. Additionally - your data contains the same value for each (year, id) pair - is it absolute?

Comment: Are the values always the same for the same id in different groups and years, like for id =1 the value is 10 in both groups in both years?

Comment: What is your MySQL Version?

Comment: The values are always the same for the same id and year. The only difference is the group. I have the most recent mysql version

Comment: With `GROUP BY year` you get two result rows, one for 2019, one for 2020. And depending on the added or not added  `WHERE` clause you will show a greater or lesser average value. What does "while preserving all the data" mean in this context? I don't understand it. What is supposed to be preserved. The result only has two columns, year and average value, right? Or do you want a different result. Then please show that in your request.

Comment: @jeffminny, check my updated answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I mean that the outer query needs to be able to access all the columns in the table so that I can filter based on those columns and still get the correct average. The `group` column in the WHERE clause is an example

Comment: I had to see DineshDB's previous answer to understand that it's an inappropriate data model we are seeing here (non-normalized, values get stored redundanty for the lack of a separate table on year and id). The real problem, however, is that late optional injection of a where clause that is always applied on the main query. It took me long to come up with a solution for this. You guessed right that the solution involves a window function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the data model is inappropriate and not normalized (you are storing values redundantly), the real problem is the late automated SQL injection (the optionally added where clause).

When a where clause gets added to your query, everything is fine, because the where clause properly restricts the rows to take into consideration (group A or B). When no where clause gets added, however, you would have to work on an aggregated data set (distinct year/id rows). The latter means an aggreation on an aggregation, which can be done with a subquery as was shown by DineshDB in an earlier answer. But here you have the problem that the where clause must work on the intermediate result (the subquery) and you say that your software adds the where clause to the main query instead.

The surprising solution to this is making this three aggregations. In below query I am mixing `MAX` (first aggregation), `AVG OVER` (second aggregation), and `DISTINCT` (third aggregation) and the three can happily co-exist in one query. No subquery is needed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  year,
  AVG(MAX(value)) OVER (PARTITION BY year)
FROM yourtable
WHERE `group` = ... -- optional where clause
GROUP BY year, id
ORDER BY year;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=973ae4f260597392c55f260d3c260084

Comment: This is good and answers the question, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it by grouping by the year only

Comment: You need the grouping by year and id first, because of the redundant values. Only then can you aggregate by year which we do with the combination of `PARTITION BY year` and `DISTINCT`. `PARTITION BY year` *is* grouping by year, only it's not decreasing the rows, for which we need an additional `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you the expected output.

```
SELECT 
  `Year`,
  AVG(DISTINCT `value`*1.0) `value`
FROM table
WHERE `group` = 'B' -- this clause is optional
GROUP BY `Year`;
```

The query will return the below results.

```
Year | Value
2019 | 20
2020 | 10
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b22c379/4)

Comment: The where clause needs to be in the outer query. The automated software cannot access subqueries.

Comment: What happens if different IDs have the same value? The avg calculation would not be correct I think. Also what is the significance of multiplying by 1.0?